Is it possible that false-positive rate decreases with increasing prevalence?
I am interested in the effect of prevalence on prediction performance. Chouldechova (2016) states that:

[w]hen using a test-fair [recidivism prediction instrument] in
populations where recidivism prevalence differs across groups, it will
generally be the case that the higher recidivism prevalence group will
have a higher FPR and lower FNR.

I want to know whether this is the case if the instrument aims for same accuracy for both groups. So I derived a function of FPR that considers accuracy, FNR and prevalence:
$$FPR=\frac{\left(1-ACC-prevalence\cdot FNR\right)}{1-prevalence}$$
This equation seems to be correct as it gives me the same results as the usual $ FPR=\frac{FP}{FP+TN}$.
I noticed that the equation only shows the positive relationship between prevalence and FPR if $FNR+ACC<1$ (i.e., sensitivity is lower than accuracy). See here.
My question is: Is it possible that the relationship between prevalence and FPR is negative in actual cases? Or am I missing something that would constrain the possible values to a realm where the relationship is positive?
EDIT: Maybe helpful for others stumbling upon this: FPR can be described as a function of base rate, accuracy, and PPV. For PPV > 0.5, the association between base rate and FPR will always be positive. For 0 < accuracy < 1: fpr = ((base+acc-1)*(ppv-1))/((base-1)*(2*ppv-1))

What exactly is your question? Your formula seems to work, judging from running it through examples, and this is a bit of algebra that should not be too hard. The relationship is indeed negative if accuracy+FNR>1. Are you asking whether this can actually happen? It absolutely can, FP=3, TP=4, FN=5, TN=5 gives you accuracy and FNR both > 0.5. But of course this example has a fixed prevalence. And that is the crux: if prevalence changes, you would typically train a new model, and now all the rates have also changed, so the comparison does not make a lot of sense.

Also, FNR, FPR etc. all suffer from the exact same issues as accuracy and can be very misleading.

Maybe a bit of context: I am looking at investigations from Dressel & Farid (2018) that found higher false-positive rates for populations with higher prevalence when using a basic logistic regression considering only two predictors. I wanted to make sure that this can be explained by the impact that prevalence has on FPR. But now I'm not sure what to make from the fact that this relationship can also have the opposite direction.

Thanks for the context, that helps. I think that little word "a logistic regression" is important here: is this a single model that is applied to different populations? Or does each population have its own logistic regression model with its own parameter estimates, plus its own prevalence and its own FPR (based on its own logistic regression model)? In any case, it looks like this is just an empirical observation for now: for each population, you have a prevalence and an FPR, and there is no mathematical reason why there should be a particular relationship between them.

It is one logistic regression fitted on the whole dataset containing members of both groups. Group identity is not considered in the algorithm. I was wondering whether the higher prevalence in one group could be a sufficient explanation for why this regression results in higher FPR for this group. This would have been the case if the relationship between prevalence and FPR is always positive - but since it is not always positive, maybe something else is at play here.

Subgroups may behave in surprising ways, see Simpson's paradox. Again, there is no a priori reason for some specific relationship, so take this just as an observation.

Thank you! That helped me clarify a few things.

Something does not seem to compute. Per your formula, the FPR could be negative (Acc+Prev+FPR>1)? Moreover, FPR (as well as TPR,TNR, FNR, and btw also Acc) is independent of the prevalence, because, by definition, it is computed by looking only at the negative subpopulation; in that subpopulation, the prevalence is 0. Now, PPV, and NPV are not independent of prevalence. Fwiw, I can derive a formlua similar to yours $FPR=\frac {(1-Acc-\frac {FN} {N})} {1-Prev}$, but N here is the total population, not just the negative subpopulation... Unless I really misunderstood your question/notation?

I rechecked my formula and I think it is correct. Of course, there is a limit to possible values so that FPR does not become > 1 or negative, but the formula itself I found to be accurate

[I presume that you mean a binary prediction setting, and the prevalence is the occurrence of the positive class.]
In evaluation, there is no direct relationship, since the prevalence is made up of TP (True Postitives) and FN (False Negatives), which have no influence on the FPR calculation.
What happens when there are similar prevalence changes in the training data, and you're looking at the whole inferential process? I'd say that nobody can really tell, it also depends on the nature of the classifier and any regularization. But you would perhaps expect that the FPR increases, since the classifier could learn a greater bias towards the positive class, potentially leading to an increase in FPs when evaluating it. But again, I don't see an explicit relationship, so it seems difficult to make absolute statements on a relationship of prevalence and FPR.

Let's start by saying that any paper which claims that FPR and/or FNR are affected by prevalence is not worth reading beyond that sentence. A key property of FPR, FNR (and TPR=Sensitivity or TNR=Specificity) is that they are independent of the prevalence (because their denominators are not the total number of cases $N$, but the total number of positive (or negative) cases), so the ratio of negative to positives plays no role.
Now the PPV and NPV do depend on the prevalence (and are monotonous functions of the prevalence), which leads to the so-called False Positive Paradox, but that is a story for another time.
Now, you can create a relationship between prevalence and FPR (or the other 3 rates), but you can do so only by modifying the threshold of the dichotomous test based on some other factor. E.g. one could use different thresholds depending on an additional categorical variable (e.g. for male or female subjects, or, apparently in the article in question, whether subjects were black or white). This may be a legitimate practice, to improve the overall test accuracy, or maybe "fairness"  (which seems to be the paper author's intent), or some other purpose. But then we really have 2 different dichotomous tests, with 2 different confusion matrices, and stating that the FPR of the test changes with prevalence is simply false; the FPR of the 2 tests may well be different, but this is a completely different statement.
Now, this issue is compounded by the fact that the OP's equation, while correct, is overspecified. The fundamental equation for FPR is $$FPR=\frac {FP} {TN+FP}$$ It depends on only 2 factors, TN and FP, which can take any positive integer value. The OP's equation is $$FPR=\frac{\left(1-Acc-Prev\cdot FNR\right)}{1-Prev}$$. This makes FPR appear to depend on 3 variables, i.e. have 3 degrees of freedom. But it only has 2; that means that the formula is not valid for all possible values of the variables (which are defined on [0,1]).
In fact, the graph presented by the OP (thanks, btw, for doing this) shows this clearly; e.g. with $Acc=0.5$ and $FNR=.1$, for any value of $Prev>.55$, the FPR is greater than 1...
Similarly, for $Acc=.9$ and $FNR=.2$, for any value of $Prev>.5$, the FPR is negative...
This proves that the OP's formula is overspecified. Because, FPR, Prevalence and Accuracy are related. In fact, we have $$(1.FNR)\cdot Prev + (1-FPR)\cdot(1-Prev)=Acc$$ Note that if you manipulate this equation, you can obtain the OP's formula; but while the above formula will give valid results for all possible values of the 4 parameters (all defined over [0,1]), it does not do so for the OP's formula (because accuracy has 4 degrees of freedom -the 4 counts in the confusion matrix-, FPR only has 2).
Last, the paper's author implies that there is a positive relationship between Prevalence and FPR. The OP's is trying to explore this, but indeed finds out that this positive relationship is only true for some combination of the 3 factors. Indeed, the first numerical example above shows a positive relationship, while the 2nd one shows a negative relationship. And for e.g. $Acc=.8$ and $FNR=.2$ (any values where $Acc+FNR=1$), there is no relationship (FPR is constant for all values of prevalence). Further proof that the paper's author statement are simply incorrect, and that a paper which wants to connect FPR and prevalence is not worth reading.

Please refer again to the formula I provided. It seems you used it incorrectly (prevalence - FNR instead of prevalence * FNR). When using the formula I provided, you will arrive at .05. I am aware that FPR and FNR are per se independent of base rate. The point is what happens if accuracy and FNR are held constant. Then FPR is fully determined by base rate.

Your formula is indeed correct. Significant edits to my answer (where I had misread your formula). However that formula is still overspecified, and the paper's author statements are fundamentally incorrect,.
